# Unless I use ModernHttp, my app is always deadlocked at the end.(Xamain.Forms-iOS)

Tags: http, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, deadlock

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms pcl.

Unless I use ModernHttp, my app is always deadlocked at the end.(Xamain.Forms-iOS).
It works fine for a while, but few hours later, every 'await' call does not back to its place.
This is a deadlock, isn't it?

My app has tons of http request call and it could be called at the same time sometimes.

This is very weird and serious problem for my app.

The problem is ModernHttp is out of date, which means the creator doesn't update library anymore. 
Maybe because of that, I'm experienced some problem with using ModernHttp. For example, UriImageSource sometimes does not load the image from web. (Works fine with built-in HttpClient)

Any tip for me?

Comment: `ModernHttpClient` on `iOS` wraps `NSURLSession` which is a part of iOS so it should never be *out of date*... that said, you can use `HttpClient` and in your `Xamarin.iOS` build options select to use `NSURLSession`, `CFNetwork` or `Managed` as your `HttpClient` implementation. `Managed` is the default for backwards compatibility, change it to `NSURLSession` and try using `HttpClient` *without* providing the `ModernHttpClient`'s `NativeMessageHandler`...

Comment: @SushiHangover It's really good to know. Thanks for many times Sushi!

Comment: @SushiHangover One more question, I assume there is similar option for Xamarin.Android, which is AndroidClientHandler. Is it better to select it instead default?

Comment: The minimum SDK of my Android project is set as API 21.

Comment: Will  there be any performance improvement if I use ModernHttp client in xamarin.android. Currently I have been using C# Httpclient.

Comment: @BrightLee The big downfall of using the `AndroidClientHandler` for your `HttpClient` implementation is that it is only available on API 21/Lollipop/5.0 and above. But that does not sound like an issue in your case ;-)

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi The managed version of `HttpClient` has its faults, it only support TLS1.0, is **slower** on encryption, and creates a slightly larger app... a lots of people love `OkHttp` due to its features, performance, ... , but `ModernHttpClient` uses OkHttp 2.4.0.3. There are bindings/nugets for OkHttp 3.5 via https://github.com/mattleibow/square-bindings

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks again!